# How to get proper "weighted" average of one column's data based on number values found in another column?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get the true average "position" in Google (as per Google Search Analytics data) for specific search query filters (e.g., all queries containing "xyz")

[Here's a link to my spreadsheet with dummy data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ueb2CRAgeZj12C2s5vC3Hs9YPOUb_-IsatkG9RqEgd4/edit#gid=1243843946).

Where I'm getting hung up is that I need to take into account the total number of Impressions for each in the **Impressions** column (column D) to get a proper average.

Here is my current formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF($B$3:$B,"*"&B1&"*",$F$3:$F)
```

How can I create a proper average?

Comment: The OP flagged this as a duplicate (not sure why that didn't reflect in the close reason).

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new column to hold either 0 or the amount of queries depending on if they contained the word [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229507/check-cell-for-a-specific-letter-or-set-of-letters), multiply that by the the average position for the query, then divide by the new column

I dropped a new sheet in your spreadsheet giving an example.

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing this! Seems to get a result, but I wonder if perhaps there is a way of doing this with the extra columns?